# can I use Heroku free addons without credit card? If I then how?

Tags: heroku

Well actually I need to use MongoLab but I also need to attach Credit Card Details which I don't have so can I use it without credit card..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use add-ons without a credit card on Heroku.
This is meant to prevent abuse (the creation of many accounts only to get many free add-ons).

Comment: Thanks I'll get it :)

Answer (score 5):

heroku-postgresql can be added without a card. At least in my case. You can try it.